# Nested triggering of events

Tags: c#, events

I have a rich text box, list box and checked list box and a button in my form.
The rich text box has loaded text file. I am searching for strings of the checked list box in the rich text box and adding the index of the found string to the list box.
On mouse double click event of the error list i am setting the cursor to that particular index position of the string.

Now i am planning to add two more buttons to the form the **Next** and previous. Which will selct the next and previous item of the listbox and cursor should point to that location . how to do that.
That is on clicking the button next the selected item should be the next to the current one, and for that i should call the mouse double click event.

```
 private void lstErrorList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //rtbFileDisplay.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            MessageBox.Show(lstErrorList.SelectedIndex.ToString());

            int val;
            string val1 = lstErrorList.Text;
            val1 = val1.Remove(0, val1.Length - 8);
            string replacement = Regex.Replace(val1, @"\t|\n|\r|[a-zA-Z]","");
            val = Convert.ToInt32(replacement);
            rtbFileDisplay.Select(val, 0);

            rtbFileDisplay.Focus();

        }
 private void btnNextError_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstErrorList.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                if (lstErrorList.SelectedIndex != lstErrorList.TopIndex)
                    lstErrorList.SelectedIndex++;
                //lstErrorList.SelectedItem = int.Parse(lstErrorList.SelectedItem + 1);

            }
    }
```

Comment: Move the code to private methods.  So you can call those methods in your code instead of having to fake a mouse event.

Comment: i able to cal the selected index changed event.But stuck up to call mouse double click of lstErrorList lstErrorList.MouseDoubleClick(sender,...here) what should replace "here"

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily considered good practice, but you can call any event with 'null' in place of sender and eventargs if you are just ignoring them anyway.